# Selinux impact on Kubernetes and Containers

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, linux-device-driver, selinux

Anyone with experience in dealing with Kubernetes/containers on an SELinux enabled cluster?
On an SELinux enforced (enable) server, what all changes required at the containers/Kubernetes level? How it can have an impact on the container process? Do we need to develop container images to support the existing SELinux policy in order to run the application efficiently?
What all the resources such as mount points, ports, etc can a container requires from the host?
Scratching my head to understand this, any inputs are appreciated.
Thanks,